# InfoPath Form published to SharePoint allows multiple users to fill out it at the same time

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

I created form by InfoPath and published to SharePoint. I am wondering that this form could be filled out by multiple users at the same time so, when they submit it then whether those submitted data will be recorded in the SharePoint list or not.

Thanks,

Xing

Answer (score 2):

Yes, multiple people can all fill in the form at the same time, no issues. Each submission will be saved in the list as separate items with their appropriate data, and of course SharePoint will also capture the username of who created the item, as well as the created date/time.